# Jquery animate in continue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate a background image in continue/infinity on the mouseover.

How can we do that ?

**[MY JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YrtY5/)**

```
$('button').mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).animate({'background-position': '100%'}, 500, 'linear');
    });

$('button').mouseout(function() { 
    $(this).animate({'background-position': '0%'}, 500, 'linear');
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "continue/infinity", do you mean you want to position animation to loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6LfEx/

```
var animatePosition = function(that){
    $(that).css({
        'background-position': '0%'
    }).animate({
        'background-position': '100%'
    }, 500, 'linear', function(){
        animatePosition(that);
    });
};
```

I would use a recursive function

Answer (score 0):

i updated your jsfiddle, [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YrtY5/3/)

```
this.handler = setInterval(function() {
       Position = Position == '0%' ? '100%' : '0%';
       $(MyParent).animate({'background-position':Position }, 500, 'linear');
    }, 500);
```

Comment: `Position = Position == '0%' ? '100%' : '0%';` just sayn'